# C*- Algebra representation and Matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $A\subset M_7$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra, where $I_7 \in A$.

Suppose $dim(A)=5$.

1. What are the possible factor and multiplicity values?
2. What are the possible dimensions of $A'$? Here $A'$ is the commutant.
3. What are the values of $dim(A')$ that uniquely determine $A$ up to *-isomorphism?

---

I want to somehow use the theorem:

Let $A \subset M_n$ be a $C^*$- algebra with $I_n \in A$. Then there are factor dimensions $n_1, \cdots, n_k$ and multiplicities $m_1, \cdots, m_k$ and a unitary $U \in M_n$ such that

- $A$ is *- isomorphic to $M_{n_1} \bigoplus \cdots \bigoplus M_{n_k}$
- $U^* AU$ is the set of block diagonal matrices, where $A_i \in M_{n_i}$ is repeated $m_i$ times
- $dim(A) = n_1^2 + \cdots n_k^2$
- $n= n_1m_1+ \cdots + n_km_k$
- $A' \simeq M_{m_1} \bigoplus \cdots \bigoplus M_{m_k}$ is the finite dimensional $C^*$ algebra with factor dimensions $m_1 , \cdots, m_k$ and multiplicities $n_1, \cdots, n_k$.
- $dim(A') = m_1^2 + \cdots m_k^2$

---

By above, we have

- $5= n_1^2 + \cdots n_k^2$
- $7= n_1m_1+ \cdots + n_km_k$.

So the factor dimensions could be $\{1,1,1,1,1 \}$, $\{1,2,0,0,0 \}$.

And the multiplicities could be $\{7, 0, 0, 0, 0 \}, \{1,3,0,0,0 \}, \{3,2,0,0,0 \}$

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track, and also a bit lost on what to do.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on track, although I don't really see how you got your multiplicities.

If all the blocks have size 1, you can make your $A$ as $\mathbb C^4\oplus \mathbb C I_3$. Or $\mathbb C^3\oplus \mathbb C I_2\oplus\mathbb C I_2$.

If you allow a block of size 2, that already gives you dimension 4, so there cannot be another one. That gives you $M_2(\mathbb C)\oplus \mathbb C I_5$. Other possibilities if you play with the multiplicities are $\big[M_2(\mathbb C)\otimes I_2\big]\oplus \mathbb C I_3$ and $\big[M_2(\mathbb C)\otimes I_3\big]\oplus \mathbb C I_1$. Here the tensor notation denotes the multiplity, i.e.
$$
M_2(\mathbb C)\otimes I_2=\Big\{\begin{bmatrix} A&0\\0&A\end{bmatrix}:\ A\in M_2(\mathbb C)\Big\}. 
$$
The three $M_2(\mathbb C)\oplus\mathbb C$ cases have multiplicities $\{1,5\}$, $\{2,3\}$, and $\{3,1\}$ respectively.

Comment: The $n_k$ is the size of the block; the $m_k$ is the number of times it is repeated. So in the first case you have $n_1=4$, $m_1=1$, $n_2=3$, $m_2=1$. In the second one you have $n_1=n_2=n_3=m_1=m_2=m_3=1$, $n_4=n_5=2$, $m_4=m_5=1$.

Comment: But according to the formula, we need to have $5= n_1^2 + \cdots n_k^2$, right?

Comment: Yeah, I got the numbers wrong. First case is $n_1=n_2=n_3=n_4=n_5=1$, $m_1=\cdots=m4=1$, $m_5=3$. In the second case I mixed the $n$ and the $m$. It's much easier to just think about the blocks.

Comment: Sorry I still don't see how you got the multiplicities with the blocks...  we know that $A$ is *-isomorphic to either $\mathbb{C} \bigoplus \mathbb{C} \bigoplus \mathbb{C} \bigoplus \mathbb{C} \bigoplus\mathbb{C} $ or $M_2 \bigoplus \mathbb{C}$. So the factor dimensions are $\{ 1,1,1,1,1\}$ and $\{ 2,1\}$. I'm not sure how you got that $\mathbb{C}^4 \bigoplus \mathbb{C}I_3 $ and $\mathbb{C}^3 \bigoplus \mathbb{C}I \bigoplus \mathbb{C}I$ in the post. Thank you for your help!

Comment: By playing with the multiplicities. When you have $\mathbb C^5$ and you have to fit in the diagonal of $M_7(\mathbb C)$, you need to stretch some of the blocks. In $\mathbb C^4\oplus\mathbb C^3$ the $m$ are $1,1,1,1,3$. In $\mathbb C^3\oplus \mathbb CI_2\oplus\mathbb C I_2$ the $m$ are $1,1,1,2,2$. You need five $m_k$ that add to $7$. That prevents you from having a 4, as the other four would put you beyond seven. So one option is $3,1,1,1,1$. If you start with $2$, then four ones are not enough, so you need $2,2,1,1,1$. And those are all the options.

Comment: I also completed the answer with more info on the $2\times 2$ case.